# /sys/block/sd*/device/timeout not accurate

Tags: linux, disk, timeout, scsi

The default value for the `timeout` file for SCSI disks is 30, supposedly meaning 30s. In my `dmesg` logs, I find that the system is waiting 180s before timing out. Setting `timeout` to various values reveals that is waiting by a multiple of six (i.e. `timeout` * 6 seconds).

Why is this happening?

(The disk access is happening through *much* indirection - a `linear` dmsetup partition on top of a `snapshot` table accessing a `loop` backed by a file on a `fuse` mount that is accessing the actual disk. Does this make a difference?)

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? If so, there may be a user rule in place. VMware Tools, for instance, will add a 180s timeout via udev rule.